# %Like mysqli% statement returning incorrectly

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query that is is trying to perform a wicard search: the form is:

```
<form name="attdate1" action="keyword.php" method="post">
     <input type=text name="hs_data" id="hs_data">
      <button class ='btn btn-lg btn-danger' type ="submit"> Search Records </button>
</form>
```

A user will enter a word to search against my database columns = hs nv vsa. If a match is found the user will get the results returned (currently in a table).

When I run the query I get just the the successful statement but no results? I new to prepared statements and have already got some good help on here. Any help is much appreciated!

my PHP :

```
<?php



$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test3");

$hs_data=$_POST['hs_data'];
$nv_data=$_POST['hs_data'];
$vsa_data=$_POST['hs_data'];

$query = $mysqli->stmt_init();
//create a prepared statement


$query = "SELECT hs,nv,vsa FROM handover WHERE hs like ? or nv like ? or vsa like ?";



$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

   $statement->bind_param('sss',$hs_data,$nv_data,$vsa_data);

//execute query
$statement->execute();

//bind result variables to be printed
$statement->bind_result( $hs,$nv,$vsa);

Print "</br></br></br></br></br><p>Your data is printed successfully</p>";
print '</br></br></br></br></br><table border="1">';

//fetch records
while($statement->fetch()) {
print '<tr>';
print '<td>'.$hs.'</td>';
print '<td>'.$nv.'</td>';
print '<td>'.$vsa.'</td>';

print '</tr>';
}   
print '</table>';

//close connection
$statement->close();
```

When I just enter a blank entry query only two of the columns in full. When I put a word in I know exists I do not get anything returned except my successful message

Comment: check the syntax for retriving results fro a querry

Comment: do those columns contain only the given string? Cause so much as I know prepare doesn't add the % for you to make it actually search for the word in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any wildcards in your `LIKE` comparison. A wildcard-less LIKE is basically exactly the same as using `=`:

```
fieldname LIKE 'foo'     identical to        fieldname = 'foo'
```

You need to do something more like:

```
$hsa = '%' . $_POST['hs_data'] . '%';
```

or directly in the query:

```
WHERE ... hsa LIKE CONCAT('%', ? , '%')
```

Comment: Thanks mark that worked - Just as an add-on if you have time where would I place a "no results". Im so used to the old SQL syntax with else statement.